# Inserting checkbox values into WordPress database

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert the values of all ticked checkboxes in a wordpress database, into a table which i created myself. Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var insert = [];
        $('.get_value').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")  ){
                insert.push($(this).val() );
            }
        });
        insert = insert.toString();
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{insert:insert},
            success:function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

and my insert code, (its in insert.php):

```
if ( isset($_POST["insert"]) ){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "status";
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
         'status' => 'approved'
    );
}
```

its not showing any errors, but its not inserting either.I dont know if this information is useful, but the checkboxes are at the admin backend as part of a custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work, because you are calling `insert.php` in your ajax call. The url should point to ajaxurl that is localized with the script where your ajax is.

So if your script is located in file called `custom.js` and you have it enqueued it like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
```

Then you'll localize your ajax url like

```
wp_localize_script( 'my_custom_script', 'ajax_call', array(
    'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
) );
```

And use it in your script like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var insert = [];        
        $('.get_value').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")  ){
                 insert.push($(this).val() );   
            }
        });
        insert = insert.toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_call.ajaxurl,
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                'action': 'my_action_callback',
                'insert': insert,
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also your insert.php code should be inside a function hooked on `wp_ajax` hooks

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback(){
    if ( isset($_POST["insert"]) ){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "status";
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
             'status' => 'approved'
        );
    }
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins