# How to insert multiple checkboxes value 0 (default) and 1 (for checked checkboxes) into Wordpress database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, web

I have plugin development requirement - 
On activation of plugin, the plugin should create one database table and by default 35 fields with '0' value should be added.
I have created a table named checkbox with 3 column inside
id(int), chk_col(varchar), created_at(timestamp)
created multiple checkboxes with value 1 as below -

```
<form action="#" id="frmPost">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="seat0" value="1">A1
    </label>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id ="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and I have script.js file where i have written validation code as below which is working fine

```
!(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmPost').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            alert('Seat ' + $(this).closest('label').text() + ' added.');
        else
            alert('Seat ' + $(this).closest('label').text() + ' removed.');
    });
    $('#frmPost').submit(function() {
        var $fields = $(this).find("input[name='seat[]']:checked");
        if (!$fields.length) {
            alert('You must book/select at least one seat!');
            return false; // The form will *not* submit
        }
    });
});
})(window.jQuery);
```

and also main wp function file is containing all necessary code
Problem is  - 
I really don't understand how to insert multiple checkboxes checked value of 1 into WP Db.
I have tried to do so but not worked at all even serialization also not able to get processed.
Help me to proceed further.
Thank you.

Here is the php code as you asked me to show
=>code I wrote -

```
function my_action_callback(){
    if ( isset($_POST["insert"]) ){
        global $wpdb;
        //$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "status";
        bus_seat_avail_table();
        $wpdb->insert(bus_seat_avail_table(), array(
             //no idea what to code here
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your PHP code? What happens with the data after the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes sure,
I am kinda stuck, not able to figure out the ajax code and hook calling and writting a function..
I have already checked out this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374769/inserting-checkbox-values-into-wordpress-database
seems somewhat of my scenario but no result sadly.

Comment: I have pasted code above.

Answer (score 0):

I got my code working by tweaking the code as per the link searched and able to insert data into database successfully.
Main code which worked from script.js(I changed code completely - jQuery and ajax)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var seats = [];       
        $('.get_value').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")  ){
                 seats.push($(this).val() );   
            }
        });
        seats = seats.toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: ticketbookingajaxurl,
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                'action': 'my_action_callback',
                'seats': seats,
                },
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The html checkbox form code been included with class="get_value"

```
<form action="#" id="frmPost">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat0" value="1">A1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat1" value="1">A2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat2" value="1">A3
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat3" value="1">A4
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat4" value="1">A5
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat5" value="1">A6
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat6" value="1">A7
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat7" value="1">A8
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat8" value="1">A9
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat9" value="1">A10
    </label><label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  id="seat34" value="1">D5
    </label></br></br>
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" id ="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally main php code which finally inserted value into WordPress DB
Hook is required for invoking the php code to wrap up in the function as shown

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback' ); //for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback' ); //for other users

function my_action_callback(){
    if ( isset($_POST["seats"]) ){
        global $wpdb;
        //$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "chkbox";
        bus_seat_avail_table();
        $wpdb->insert(bus_seat_avail_table(), array(
             'chk_col' => '1' //chk_col is the column name in DB
        ));
        //wp_die();//compulsory 
    }
}
```

> > But I am not able to understand whether all fields for unchecked checkbox value should remain 0 and checked should be saved as 1.
> >     What I want is to understand the approach where the saved value should automatically save to 1 inside DB and unchecked should be 0 in the same chk_col field, But no luck so far.
> >     Help me to understand please.....